# Saving file into data structure maintained as attribute of class

Tags: python, class, data-structures

I'm making a Scrabbler Helper program.

In this assignment, In one class includes the Scrabbler Dictionary, Create a class to manage the Scrabble dictionary.

Its ***init**()* method should read the *words.txt* file into a suitable data structure maintained as an attribute of the class.

I'm not sure what this means?

Comment: It means, you need to see how words.txt is structured. If it's list of words separated by new line. [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) is appropriate data structure.

Comment: It is a list of words. We've never been taught how to get a init() method to read a file before. The words.txt file is a list of words separated by a new line. I'm not sure how to read the words.txt file into a list(?). And this list is supposed to be an attribute of the class?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create multiple instances of `ScrabblerDictionary`, it's better to read the file into list before creating instance.

Here is a short snippet you can use:

```
  class ScrablerDictionary:
    def __init__(self, words):
      self.words = words


  def main():
    with open('words.txt') as f:
      words = f.read().splitlines()

    scrabler = ScrablerDictionary(words)
    print(scrabler.words)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```